# T-SQL update column with case statement when between two values from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables and I would like to update the `Possession` column in `Table1` when day is between `StartDay` and `EndDay` of `Table2`.

**Table1**

| CompanyId | Day | GroupId | Possession |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 5 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 7 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 7 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 8 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 9 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 9 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 10 | 2 | 0 |

**Table2**

| CompanyId | GroupId | StartDay | EndDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 99 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 99 | 1 | 6 | 7 |
| 99 | 2 | 8 | 10 |

This is the update statement I wrote but `Table1` is only updating for the first row of `Table2`. I need it to update for every row of `Table2`.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Possession = 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.Day BETWEEN b.StartDay AND b.EndDay
             AND a.GroupId = b.GroupId 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.CompanyId = b.CompanyId
```

This is my desired outcome

| CompanyId | Day | GroupId | Possession |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 99 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 99 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 99 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 99 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 99 | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 99 | 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 99 | 7 | 2 | 0 |
| 99 | 8 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 8 | 2 | 1 |
| 99 | 9 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 9 | 2 | 1 |
| 99 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 99 | 10 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Break it down. Looking at only the "first" row in Table1, you can (should?) see that it joins to all four rows in Table2. The updated column can only hold a single value, so which row from Table2 do YOU think should be used in your CASE expression? And WHY do you think that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join condition is not correct, each row from `a` is matching with each row of `b` so you are updating each row of `a` 4 times, which 1 of the 4 should be used?

You could use an outer join with all criteria but this is better written using *exists*

```
Update a 
 set a.possession=
 case when exists (
    select * from table2 b 
    where b.CompanyId=a.companyId 
      and b.groupId=a.groupId 
      and a.day between b.startday and b.endday
) then 1 else 0 end
from 
table1 a;
```